Multiple "applications" in CherryPy producing 404s?
I am posting this question, because all the other posts regarding the issue I am facing are all 11 years old.   I am sure quite a bit has changed between now and them, so I do not trust those articles.
I was able to successfully deploy a CherryPy configuration using the cherrypy.quickstart method, and all worked great.
I now have some more capability I am trying to add to the existing Python script, so I need to have additional applications, so I found this in the CherryPy documentation:
https://docs.cherrypy.dev/en/latest/basics.html#hosting-one-or-more-applications
Without a ton of information available, I followed those steps, and all the objects exist that the cherrypy.tree.mount is referring to, yet I am getting a "404" path not found.
    cherrypy.config.update(
        {
            "log.screen": True,
            "server.socket_host": "scriptbox.its.utexas.edu",
            "server.socket_port": 8888,
            "server.ssl_module": "builtin",
            "server.ssl_certificate": scriptPath()+"/ssl/scriptbox.pem",
            "server.ssl_private_key": scriptPath()+"/ssl/scriptbox.key",
            "server.ssl_certificate_chain": scriptPath()+"/ssl/server_chain.pem",
            "/favicon.ico":
                {
                    'tools.staticfile.on': True,
                    'tools.staticfile.filename': '/f5tools.ico'
                }
        })

    cherrypy.tree.mount(ServeHelp(), '/')
    cherrypy.tree.mount(AS3Tools(), '/as3tohtml')
    cherrypy.tree.mount(ServeReport(), '/net_report')

    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()

The instance starts successfully.  If you go to "/" (root), that works just fine.
If I go to either "/as3tohtml" or "/net_report", I get the following error:
404 Not Found

The path '/as3tohtml/' was not found.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/p3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 659, in respond
    self._do_respond(path_info)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/p3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 718, in _do_respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/p3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 223, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/p3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cherrypy/_cperror.py", line 415, in __call__
    raise self
cherrypy._cperror.NotFound: (404, "The path '/as3tohtml/' was not found.")


The code around the calls above are:
class AS3Tools:
    @cherrypy.expose
    def as3tohtml(self, env, as3_file):
        as3 = AS3Declaration(env+"/"+as3_file)
        if as3.getStatus():
            return parse_as3(as3)

and ...
class ServeReport:
    @cherrypy.expose
    def network_report(self):
        net_report = NetworkReport()
        if net_report.getStatus():
            return generate_report(net_report)

What am I doing wrong?  Help?
